# make increment text with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, text, increment

I want to make if function with increment text

I already have a function that can append a new line of text to a .txt file with if condition. But it don't know how to make the number of the text increase from 1 to n.
I'm not good at code. Can someone explain to me how to create a function in python?

The condition is like this :

If the value in column dataframe ['similarity'] is greater than 0.5 , and the value in other column dataframe ['polarity'] is "POSITIF". Then , i want to append a new line of text to a .txt file.
ex : given a table like this

| text | similarity | polarity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABCDD | 0.6 | POSITIF |
| ASDAS | 0.4 | NEGATIF |
| ASGAS | 1.0 | POSITIF |

Here's the code that i use :

```
with open("test.txt","a") as myfile:
for key, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row['Similarity'] > 0.5) and ('POSITIF' in row['polarity']): 
        myfile.writelines(':membangun(i) rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;\n
        rdfs:subPropertyOf :membangun .')
```

The text should be like this :

[image: text]

Comment: What if you say `myfile.writelines(f':membangun(key) rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;\n rdfs:subPropertyOf :membangun .')`

Comment: I've tried it , but it print " rdfs:subPropertyOf :membangun .:membangun(key) rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
 rdfs:subPropertyOf :membangun ."

Comment: Sorry, I had a type:
`myfile.writelines(f':membangun({key}) rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;\n rdfs:subPropertyOf :membangun .')`
I forgot `{}` arround key.